# Is there interval notation for out-of-range?

Tags: notation

I often find code that checks for out of range values, as in:

```
if (x < 5 or x > 6) {
 // do stuff...
}
```

I like to rearrange it to get a slightly better visual cue:

```
if (x < 5 or 6 < x) {
 // do stuff...
}
```

My question is whether there is mathematical notation for that. I'm no mathematician; I know about inequality/comparison operators and interval notation for closed and open-ended (between) ranges, but I have yet to stumble upon a good, concise representation for out-of-range.

I'm left with writing the inequalities, or the rather clumsy "all except" interval notation (−∞,5) ∪ (6,∞), So let's say I propose something in the lines of

```
<a,b<
```

as new interval notation; how would I go about getting it accepted?

Comment: How about $x \notin [5,6]$?

Comment: Brilliant, negation--of course. Now I feel silly. Thanks!

Comment: In my next language: if (a <= x <= b), with negation as the best option :)